# Problems with running a 2nd installation of Wordpress on my domain?

Tags: customization, htaccess, directory, subdomains

I have a WP installation in the root of my domain (running on Apache / Linux).

I need to create a new WP installation (for various reasons that are outside of this post) and I have a choice of creating this second installation within either a) a subdomain or b) a folder in the main domain.

So I can create this new installation in either **new.mydomain.com** or **mydomain.com/new/**

For SEO and other reasons I prefer to go for the latter ie. creating this new WP installation in a folder.

However, I'm concerned about what problems I might run into. For example, the "main WP installation" (in root) has a htaccess file. Rules in that htaccess file might impact the new WP installation in the folder. So if the root htaccess had, for example, a block on a certain IP then that IP might not be able to access mydomain.com/new/

Am I right to be concerned about issues with files in root like htaccess and robots.txt (and sitemap and others)? What problems am I likely to run into? What can I do to alleviate these problems?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: "Rules in that htaccess file might impact the new WP installation in the folder." - yes, that is possible. And yes, depending on how the IP block was implemented then this could also influence the sub-WordPress installation. "What problems am I likely to run into?" - well, that's really a bit open ended as it depends on the site and what directives you have. With regards to `.htaccess`, you can usually override parent directives in the child `.htaccess` file (including IP blocking) - but this "override" is something that you would need to explicitly implement.

Comment: Many thanks, MrWhite. With respect the "problems I'm likely to run into" I was hoping for any suggestions of general areas to watch out for (rather than a list of specific problems). The overriding parent directives in the child htaccess is interesting, thanks. I shall investigate that.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid `.htaccess` files of WP installations, affect other WP installations, use the following file system structure:

> ```
> hosting_account_folder
>     ┌─────┴─────┐ 
> public_html subdomains
>            ┌────┼────┐
>           sub1 sub2 sub3
> ```

In this scenario, `mydomain.com` points to `hosting_account_folder/public_html`, `sub1.mydomain.com` points to `hosting_account_folder/subdomains/sub1`, `sub2.mydomain.com` points to `hosting_account_folder/subdomains/sub2`, and `sub3.mydomain.com` points to `hosting_account_folder/subdomains/sub3`.

As you can see, none of WP installations, is a subfolder of any other WP installation.

**Note:** having a WP installation, as a subfolder of another installation, is not good for SEO, it is a myth. Always use subdomains!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Frank. While I completely agree with you on your suggestion being the ideal layout, I am not convinced about your comment regarding the SEO being a myth. I have researched this quite extensively - including testing sub-domain vs sub-directory on other websites I own - and I am convinced that, contrary to Google's utterances on the subject, sub-directory has a distinct SEO advantage. But that's a discussion / debate for another time. 

For now, I think I've found a solution which I shall post below.

Answer (score 0):

After much hunting, I think I've found an answer: 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass

Any comments on this are welcome.